# Animate view regardless of its layout-container

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I'm trying to apply a `TranslateAnimation` to an `ImageView` inside of a `LinearLayout`. As soon as the `ImageView`(marked "1" in the image below) crosses the bounds of the `LinearLayout` that contains the `ImageView`, it goes "black"/disappears. This does NOT happen if I animate the entire green `LinearLayout`, so I don't think it has to do with it's `z`-value. Rather, I believe that the `ImageView` can't visually "escape" its container layout (green). What can I do to make the `ImageView` display in front of everything when the animation is being performed? I've already tried `.bringToFront()`(followed by `.requestLayout`/`.invalidate` of the root view).

[image]

Comment: Try to set android:clipChildren="false" in a parent container

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you very much :-)! Would you like to post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set android:clipChildren="false" in a parent container